# how to let kamailio use different mysql peer users table

Tags: mysql, kamailio

I create my own users table with different name and different field name, i want to let kamailio use it as 'acc' table for peer users how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

acc table in kamailio is for accounting records (i.e., billing data).

I understand you want to use a different table for user profiles (the user account details such as username and password). If yes, then look at the readme for auth_db -- the module has parameters for setting column names:

- http://kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/modules/auth_db.html

The name of the table is given as parameter to authentication functions from the module (e.g., see auth_check() docs).

Be sure you disable table version check via version_table parameter from same module.